# Configure Qt project (.pro file) to use PcapPlusPlus

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake, pcapplusplus

I want to use Pcap++ inside my Qt project.
I've followed steps in the installation & introduction guide of PcapPlusPlus, but there are still unknowns:

- How do I implement that in my .pro file : `include ../../../Dist/mk/PcapPlusPlus.mk`
- And that:

```
all: 
    g++.exe $(PCAPPP_INCLUDES) -c -o main.o main.cpp
    g++.exe $(PCAPPP_LIBS_DIR) -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o Tutorial-LiveTraffic.exe main.o $(PCAPPP_LIBS)
```

I've already add my LIBS and my INCLUDEPATH like that :

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/libCommon++.a -lCommon++
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/libPacket++.a -lPacket++
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/libPcap++.a -lPcap++
LIBS += -lpcap

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/pcapplusplus
```

And to give you an example, when I try to call code as follow in my main function:

```
#include <IPv4Layer.h>
#include <Packet.h>
#include <PcapFileDevice.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    pcpp::PcapFileReaderDevice reader("the/path/example-app/1_packet.pcap");

    return 0;
}
```

I got a lot of errors like this :

```
/tmp/cirrus-ci-build/PcapPlusPlus/Common++/header/Logger.h:173: error : undefined reference to `pcpp::LoggerPP::LoggerPP()'
```

Comment: Regardless of everysthiong else, you have an error in `LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/libCommon++.a -lCommon++` => this should be `LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lCommon++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to convert the .mk to an appropriate code that qmake understands, for example in my case the .mk is:

```
PCAPPLUSPLUS_HOME := /home/developer/PcapPlusPlus-20.08

### COMMON ###

# includes
PCAPPP_INCLUDES := -I$(PCAPPLUSPLUS_HOME)/Dist/header

# libs dir
PCAPPP_LIBS_DIR := -L$(PCAPPLUSPLUS_HOME)/Dist

# libs
PCAPPP_LIBS := -lPcap++ -lPacket++ -lCommon++

# post build
PCAPPP_POST_BUILD :=

# build flags
PCAPPP_BUILD_FLAGS :=

ifdef PCAPPP_ENABLE_CPP_FEATURE_DETECTION
    PCAPPP_BUILD_FLAGS += -DPCAPPP_CPP_FEATURE_DETECTION -std=c++11
endif

ifndef CXXFLAGS
CXXFLAGS := -O2 -g -Wall
endif

PCAPPP_BUILD_FLAGS += $(CXXFLAGS)
### LINUX ###

# includes
PCAPPP_INCLUDES += -I/usr/include/netinet

# libs
PCAPPP_LIBS += -lpcap -lpthread

# allow user to add custom LDFLAGS
PCAPPP_BUILD_FLAGS += $(LDFLAGS)
```

So using the previous information build the following .pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

PCAPPLUSPLUS_HOME = /home/developer/PcapPlusPlus-20.08

PCAPPP_INCLUDES = $${PCAPPLUSPLUS_HOME}/Dist/header
PCAPPP_LIBS_DIR = -L$${PCAPPLUSPLUS_HOME}/Dist
PCAPPP_LIBS = -lPcap++ -lPacket++ -lCommon++
PCAPPP_POST_BUILD =
PCAPPP_BUILD_FLAGS =
defined(!PCAPPP_ENABLE_CPP_FEATURE_DETECTION){
    PCAPPP_BUILD_FLAGS += -DPCAPPP_CPP_FEATURE_DETECTION -std=c++11
}
defined(!CXXFLAGS){
    CXXFLAGS = -O2 -g -Wall
}
PCAPPP_BUILD_FLAGS += $${CXXFLAGS}
PCAPPP_INCLUDES += -I/usr/include/netinet
PCAPPP_LIBS += -lpcap -lpthread
PCAPPP_BUILD_FLAGS += $${LDFLAGS}

LIBS += $${PCAPPP_LIBS}
INCLUDEPATH += $${PCAPPP_INCLUDES}
DEPENDPATH += $${PCAPPP_LIBS_DIR}
```

Comment: Ok, I think, I can just say thanks you that work perfectly ! Subject is closed!

Comment: Hi , I did Exactly what you said but I still got `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPcap++: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPacket++: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCommon++: No such file or directory`  error The only thing I did was installed it using brew (brew install pcapplusplus), I use fedora 38